# create excel file using asp.net web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am using an external DLL for creating Excel file. It is perfectly working in web page, but when i am using it via Web service it does not give any error, but does not create any file too. Here is the code of web service and excel export function.

```
    [WebMethod, System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
    public static string DownloadProfile(string profileids)
    {
        Result pro = new Result();
        if (profileids == "")
            pro = new Result(0, false, "No Profile to download", "");
        else
        {
            candidate_search cs = new candidate_search();
            string SqlProfile = "query";

            try
            {
                cs.ExportExcel(SqlProfile);
                pro = new Result(0, true, "CV Downloaded Successfully !", "");
            }
            catch { 
                //pro = new Result(0, false, "No Profile to download", ""); 
            }
        }

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pro, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
        return json;
    }

    public void ExportExcel(string SQLqueryProfile)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection ConProfile = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand CmdProfile = new SqlCommand(SQLqueryProfile);
        SqlDataAdapter SdaProfile = new SqlDataAdapter();
        CmdProfile.Connection = ConProfile;
        SdaProfile.SelectCommand = CmdProfile;
        DataTable DtProfile = new DataTable();
        SdaProfile.Fill(DtProfile);

        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(DtProfile, "Profile");
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=dataExport.xlsx");
            using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is no error. but does not create any excel file.

Comment: Use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no error you can do two things:

1. Debug. Maybe there's an error that's being thrown and swallowed?
2. I see you're writing the file to the response. Write it to disk instead and see if that works.